# How can I make my .muttrc portable to older machines despite "unknown variable"

Tags: mutt

On an older machine, which I am not an administrator of, I can't use my
global `.muttrc`, without getting

```
Error in /home/jidanni1/.muttrc, line 18: sidebar_visible: unknown variable
source: errors in /home/jidanni1/.muttrc
```

Is there some way for me to still be able to use the same `.muttrc` on both
new and old machines, without getting this error?

Comment: sure: don't use the newer features.  mutt doesn't provide conditionals, and the other alternative would be to force it to read different files.

Comment: I probably would need to make a wrapper ~/bin/mutt that detects mutt version and then calls real mutt with a certain -F .